# search json value for the first img tag in a string using javascript or angularjs specific filter

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Working on an angular project and came across a situation where one of the endpoints doesnt exactly return an easily useable image object..

Say you have a json object in the console which returns something like:

```
__cdata: "Some random text here and <img src="image.jpg">"
```

How would you go about searching the `__cdata` value for that first img tag and storing that src? I guess this technically doesn't have to be an angular specific solution either, but curious if one exists. Thanks

Comment: Heyo! Not too sure either as whether there's an Angular specific method but all that I can think of is to do a string search and take out location in the src attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to wrap your string in 'single-quotes', not "double-quotes", if you intend for your `img src` to use "double-quotes". Otherwise your string will break at the `src` tag.

Anyway, you can leverage string.indexOf:

```
var tagIndex = __cdata.indexOf('<img'); // Find where the img tag starts
var srcIndex = __cdata.substring(tagIndex).indexOf('src=') + tagIndex; // Find where the src attribute starts
var urlStart = srcIndex + 5; // Find where the actual image URL starts; 5 for the length of 'src="'
var urlEnd = __cdata.substring(urlStart).indexOf('"') + urlStart; // Find where the URL ends
var src = __cdata.substring(urlStart, urlEnd); // Extract just the URL
```

Comment: ah, whoops. Pardon my sloppy code. We Gregs gotta stick together! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use RegExp:

```
var matches = String(text).match(/<img.*?src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(?:<\/img>)?/m);
result = (matches && matches.length && matches[1]) ? matches[1] : '';
```